# What exactly do the French diacritics denote? And can they be implied/expelled?

Tags: prononciation, diacritiques

French scrub here.

Can someone explain to me what the French diacritics denote?
What do they change about pronunciation, are how consistent are they?
And when, if ever, are they allow to be redacted from their character?

I've been searching but haven't found much.
Whether that means there's little info on this or that I'm blind I cannot say.

Comment: Similaire: [L'orientation des accents est-elle liée à l'intonation ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13378)

Comment: They often change the pronunciation and the meaning, and when they exist in a word they are mandatory (exceptions: few words can be written with or without an accent because of the 1990 spelling reform).

Comment: On a related note, there is apparently at least one diacritic that was added for the sole purpose of distinguishing two words: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/do%c3%b9-vient-le-%c3%b9-de-o%c3%b9

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Diacritics are part of French orthography. To take one example, "dû" is the past participle of "devoir". If you remove the circumflex, it becomes "du", the contraction of "de" + "le".

Different diacritics denote different things. The circumflex over an vowel often marks where an "s" used to follow the vowel. So modern French "êtes" is "estes" in old French. The "s" in the middle was dropped, and a circumflex placed above the "e". English speakers can mentally insert an "s" after a circumflex and guess at a word:

- forêt => forest
- hôpital => hospital
- tempête => tempest

Accent aigu changes the pronunciation. "parle" as in "elle parle" ("she talks") has one syllable and rhymes with the first name "Carl". But "parlé" as in "elle a parlé" ("she talked" or "she has talked") has two syllables; the first rhymes with "Carl", the second with "hay", like "parlay" (and yes, that's a cognate).

The cedilla makes a "c" soft where it would otherwise be hard, so "français" has a soft "c" in the middle, like an "s".

Search Wikipedia and you can learn about other diacritics and other uses for the diacritics I mentioned.

It is acceptable to omit diacritics from capitalized letters, but not from lowercase ones.

**edit**:
As noted in the comments, while diacritics are often omitted from capital letters, this is considered non-standard by the Académie Française for precisely the reasons listed above: diacritics are part of French orthography, and removing them leads to ambiguity.

Comment: About your last statement see http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters/67#67

Comment: @btrem - your last statement is incorrect. It happens, but it is not considered acceptable by the Académie Française (see jlliagre's link).

Comment: @Frank Prescriptivism vs descriptivism - the age-old argument. Technically, his statement is neither correct nor incorrect. L'Académie Française, aussi bien que les textes de grammaire, peuvent considérer un tel usage 'incorrecte', mais la majorité des francophones font cette 'faute', donc est-ce vraiment une faute? Le même truc se passe en anglais, mais personne s'en fiche à moins que c'est de langage très formel à l'écrit.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - oui bien sûr. I think a correct answer would state the position of the Académie, state the everyday practice, and leave it at that. In facts, words such as "acceptable" or "correct" should be proscribed, or at least presented with the appropriate context about who he saying it is "acceptable" or "correct" and why.

Comment: @Frank Absolutely agreed - one can present the arguments for both 'sides', and leave it to the user of the language to make their own choices, once made aware of the implications :) Personally I find it a lot easier to read French if the diacritics are present for capital letters, so I prefer to use them myself.

Comment: Which is also one of the arguments of the Académie, in a link supplied in the link above. They say it helps with reading more comfortable and possibly with disambiguating in some cases.

Comment: The French academy is responsible for "le bon usage" as well, so it's good to rectify grave errors, even if 90% of the population is wrong. About the circumflex accent, it often denotes the disappearance of a letter in general, not just the letter 's' (but most of the time it was an 's' indeed). It is also used for disambiguation (du/dû), as well as for 'e' who are pronounced with either grave or accute accent depending on the position in the word.

Comment: "_It is acceptable to omit diacritics from capitalized letters, but not from lowercase ones._": it has been acceptable until the 90's. Nowadays we've got better computer software which handle diacritics on upper case letters. Please read [what the Académie française have to say about this](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong). (oops, dupe comment >_<)

Comment: "It's good to rectify grave errors, even if 90% of the population is wrong" really embodies the prescriptivist approach. ;) I like @Frank's method described in answer 4 above.

Comment: I stand corrected on the use of diacritics with capital letters, and have edited my answer. Thanks to  jlliagre and Frank for pointing out the position of the Académie.

Comment: In Belgium at least, I remembered being taught to NOT USE diacritics on capitals...  but it was something like 30 years ago, and indeed in the meantime the prescription has changed. I also couldn't tell (or find) the rule for cursive script as all examples I find are with printscript...

Answer (score 16):

For reference, the usual diacritics are as follows.

---

### Accent aigu: é

**Pronunciation:** Uniformly causes the vowel to be pronounced [e] (as in English "may").

There are some rare exceptions where it's pronounced [ɛ] (as in English "beg") instead, such as *év**é**nement* (recommended spelling changed to *év**è**nement* in 1990) and in inversions like [*aimé-je*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24876/extra-vowel-before-inverted-je).

**Usage:** Most notably on past participles of *-er* verbs, such as *parlé*. Many nouns end in it as well, such as *musée*. Besides that, it's simply to mark the "ay" sound in many words, such as *présenter*. One word that shows both cases is the surprising *créé* (past tense of *créer*).

**Notes:** An *e* without an accent sometimes disappears from pronunciation (the *e muet*). However, if it has **any** accent, this is not possible. An *e* with an accent other than é is generally pronounced [ɛ].

---

### Cédille: ç

**Pronunciation:** Causes a hard *c* [k] to be pronounced as a soft *c* [s] instead.

**Usage and notes:** See [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/why-is-there-no-cedilla-on-the-c-in-porcelaine/25054#25054).

---

### Tréma: ä ë ï ö ü ÿ

**Pronunciation:** Pronounce this and the preceding vowel as two distinct sounds.

**Usage:** Purely used in fixed forms, not triggered by any grammatical shift. Some examples are *aïeux*, *ambiguë*, and borrowed words from languages that use this more often, such as *Hawaï*.

**Notes:** ï is by far the most common, followed by ë.

---

### Accent grave: à è ù

**Pronunciation:** This accent on à and ù does not change their pronunciation. However, è is pronounced [ɛ].

**Usage:** à and ù are only in fixed forms, such as *là* "there" vs. *la* "the" and *où* "where" vs. *ou* "or". However, è can appear not only in fixed forms, such as the common ending *-ère* (*père*, *prière*, *bière*), but also grammatically.

Specifically, it appears when an e that is normally *caduc* becomes *obligatoire* as a result of conjugation. For example, in the verb *lever*, the first vowel is reduced or even dropped. But in the present-tense conjugation *lève*, which has only one syllable, the stress has moved back to the first *e* and it is no longer optional. This is marked with the accent grave. (This is not 100% regular.)

---

### Accent circonflexe: â, ê, î, ô, û

**Pronunciation:** The vowel usually becomes the variant it would have in an open/"long" syllable. The difference is negligible for î and û. For ê, the same note as above applies: if it has an accent, this letter can't be silent. For â, it becomes a back vowel [ɑ]; compare *[sache](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/sache)* and *[lâche](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/l%C3%A2che)*.

**Usage:** A few different purposes. One is to distinguish words, e.g. *du* "of the" vs. *dû* "had to" or *jeune* "young" vs. *jeûne* "a fast from food". Another is to signal historical letters that have disappeared, often *s*, as in *fête*, *honnête*, *forêt* (compare *feast*, *honest*, *forest*). It also regularly appears in certain conjugations, such as the passé simple and the past subjunctive.

---

Capital letters are often written without their accents. This leads to some amusing situations, like this sign I saw at the Eiffel Tower advertising some seemingly unappealing snacks:

> BRETZELS SALES

(*salé* "salted" vs. *sale* "dirty")

*Edit:* As jlliagre and Frank point out, although it is common practice, omitting accents on capital letters [is not considered correct French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters/67#67) by the Académie.

P.S. Here are cross-platform [instructions](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/french/matheis/1102fa01/edit/accents.html) on typing all of them. *Edit:* Here is a [script](https://sawczak.com/en/maccents/) written in [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) that allows you to type French and Spanish accents on a PC as you would on a Mac.

Comment: See jlliagre's link in comment above: omitting diacritic marks, on capitals or anywhere else, is not acceptable for the Académie Française, which notes it was just a base and vile mercantile trick to lower impression costs, I suppose in olden times before computers would make adding the accents inexpensive :-)

Comment: @Frank Fair enough -- edited to clarify. Another theory that reverses the computer era hypothesis: it's already so dang hard to memorize one set of accent ALT codes, in PC environments, anyway. When the second one comes along, we throw up our hands. Why can't we all just adopt the generalized Apple method: choose accent, choose letter, not 30+ codes...

Comment: You can change the keyboard layout setting to one that includes ["dead" keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key): these are keys that don't enter anything by themselves, but add an accent to the next letter typed. Also, in many Linux systems you can press the [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) (whichever key you've configured that to be), then type a letter and an accent.

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one! For upper case and accents, it's extremely easy at least for Linux users : just use `caps lock` and write an accented letter to have its upper case equivalent.

Comment: The syllable containing ‹ô› is open (e.g. , in « pôle », « polynôme »), but the vowel itself is closed. It is pronounced [o], not [ↄ] (open « o »). Note that if the syllable is closed, the graphème ‹ô› usually (always ?) becomes ‹o›, but it is still pronounced [o], as in « polaire », « polynomial ».

Comment: Aussi au Canada il est facile de se procurer un clavier qwerty avec les accents et les guillemets français (je pense qu'on appelle ça un clavier _canadian multilingual_)... ça n'empêche pas de l'utiliser pour écrire en anglais ; j'utilise le _language bar_ encastré près de l'heure dans Win. pour changer entre _Canadian French_ et _U.S._ selon l'utilisation que j'en fais...

Comment: @Jardindefrostedflakes C'est vrai, mais je ne m'y suis jamais habitué pour quelque raison ... Je ne sais pas pourquoi. Si frustrant d'avoir un « É » là où je m'attendais à un « ? » !

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure: they cannot be redacted from their character, under any circumstance. This is just not an option if you want to write correct French. What's more, if you omit them, you might introduce ambiguities, because those diacritics sometimes distinguish important variations.

Answer (score 1):

As @btrem and Luke Sawczak have said in relation to ê, the circumflex placed above an e often denotes an obsolete adjacent s, as in forêt, hôpital and tempête. Similarly, é at the beginning of a word often also denotes an s found in English words: élève (slave), école (school), étudier (study) etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure élève is derived from élever (elevare) without any former s.

Comment: Thanks, Frenzie. My apology - you're right. I'll swap you for écaler, écoper, écosse, écrivain, épice, éponge, étable, établir, étage, étal, état, étampe, étanche and étrangler. No doubt there are others.